# How can I use the java for each loop with custom classes?

Tags: java, class, foreach

I think most coders have used code like the following :

```
ArrayList<String> myStringList = getStringList();
for(String str : myStringList)
{
   doSomethingWith(str);
}
```

How can I take advantage of the for each loop with my own classes? Is there an interface I should be implementing?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can implement [Iterable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Here's an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/CreatingIterableObjectsusingaforeachforlooponanIterableobject.htm). It's not the best, as the object is its own iterator. However it should give you an idea as to what's going on.

Comment: Implementation which have both `Iterator<>` and `Iterable<>` implemented has side effect: http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/03/javas-iterators-and-iterables.html ("An Iterator should not be Iterable!" section). Be warned.

Comment: In this example, no new iterators are being created. Doesn't this only work for one iteration because `this` is always being returned?

Answer (score 23):

The short version of for loop (`T` stands for my custom type):

```
for (T var : coll) {
    //body of the loop
}
```

is translated into:

```
for (Iterator<T> iter = coll.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    T var = iter.next();
    //body of the loop
}
```

and the Iterator for my collection might look like this:

```
class MyCollection<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    public int size() { /*... */ }

    public T get(int i) { /*... */ }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }

    class MyIterator implements Iterator<T> {

        private int index = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < size();
        }

        public type next() {
            return get(index++);
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not supported yet");

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, searched the internet for this

Answer (score 10):

You have to implement the Iterable [interface](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), that is to say, you have to implement the method

```
class MyClass implements Iterable<YourType>
{
Iterator<YourType> iterator()
  {
  return ...;//an iterator over your data
  }
}
```